# Finding the total number of rows for all tables in CockroachDB

Tags: cockroachdb

I’m curious how many total rows I have across all of the tables in my deployment. Does CockroachDB have a command to count the total number of rows in all of my tables?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We don't currently have anything that's better than running a `SELECT COUNT(*)` query against every table in your database, which will be really slow. Instead, we recommend using the data size in the admin UI as an approximation.

If the exact count of all rows is still desired, you can can use a shell script to gather all the table names from `information_schema` and issue a `COUNT(*)` query for all of them.

For example, the following snippet will print out the row counts for every table in the database `cats`:

```
tables=$(cockroach sql -e "SELECT table_name FROM information_schema.tables WHERE table_schema='cats'" | sed 1,2d)
for table in $tables; do
  cockroach sql -e "SELECT '$table', COUNT(*) FROM cats.$table"
done
```

Comment: I used `tables=$(cockroach sql --insecure -e "use cats; select table_name from [show tables] order by table_name;" | sed 1,2d)`